# How do I set up a named pipe between .NET and MFC?

Tags: .net, wpf, mfc, named-pipes

How do I set up named pipe between a .NET (specifically WPF) application and an MFC application running in the background?  I need to provide synchronous and asynchronous messaging sending XML instances.  Is there a way to use a call back architecture?

Comment: Is named pipes a must if they both run on the same system? MMF is better for local communication, and old good sockets are better across network.

Comment: Named pipe is a named pipe - just special memory buffer.  You just need to determine which app is the server and which one is the client.  The rest is specific to MFC, .NET - and not hard at all, if you read docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the MFC application: I don't think there are any MFC classes specifically to help with named pipes, but the Windows Named Pipes API is not too difficult, or you could look to open source/shareware classes for higher level abstractions ([for example here](http://www.naughter.com/npipe.html))

In the .NET application, the types in the System.IO.Pipes namespace provide a nice stream abstraction over a named pipe which is fairly straightforward to use.

Decisions you will have to make include:

1. Which application is the pipe server, responsible for creating the pipe and listening for the other application (pipe client) to connect.
2. Can you work directly with the message-streaming mode provided by the OS (each write to the pipe is deemed one message), or do you need to build your own message framing over the pipe byte-stream.

Duplex operation is supported, so you can build "callback architecture" over the pipe messaging if you want to.

Windows Communication Framework provides a Named Pipe transport binding. But this won't be useful to you even on the WPF application side unless you are up for reimplementing on the MFC side a host of partly-documented Microsoft protocols layered on top of the raw pipe communication (you can read more on this [on my blog](http://blogs.charteris.com/blogs/chrisdi/archive/tags/Named+Pipes/default.aspx) if you are interested).

Comment: I am wanting to create a Request/Response architecture. Can named pipes even provide such a thing?  Does the server/client have to spin uselessly while waiting on the server?

Comment: You can build a Request/Response architecture over a named pipe transport, but the named pipe itself doesn't give you this: it is just a duplex communication transport. The APIs on both sides support asynchronous IO patterns.